# Apache2 Default overrides virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, wordpress

I have an Ubuntu 12.10 LTS server running apache2 with a simple wordpress install.  I created the virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-available and used a2ensite to enable it.  All was working fine for two days.

This morning I woke up to check the site and it seemed the virtual host was not working at all.  It kept going to the default site in apache2.

Here is my config:

default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

virtual host: domain.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin me@domain.com
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias www.domain.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/domain.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/domain.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/domain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see I have two separate configs with no conflicts.  But apache2 keeps reverting to the default site instead of the name-based vhost.  My /etc/hosts file is correct and has a FQDN and host name pointed to the public-facing IP as well.  This just happened overnight.

I ran a a2dissite on domain.com, apache2 reload, then a2ensite on domain.com with no results.  I ended up having to a2dissite the default config.  Once I did that the domain.com site came up with my wordpress site just fine.

Any idea why this happened?  I've ran apache2 and nginx for years and have never had a problem with virtual hosting.  This one is a bit weird.  I shouldn't have to disable the default site for my other virtual host to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have options NameVirtualHost *:80 and Listen *:80 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

> ServerName localhost

into the default virtual host. Also you could temporarily disable the *< Directory / >* section from the default virtual host, it seems to be useless.

Comment: Adding ServerName localhost to the default virtual host seemed to solve the problem.  What I don't understand is that it's been working fine with the config I posted for 2 days.  All of a sudden overnight it stopped working.  Apache2 wasn't even killed or reloaded.  The vhosting just stopped working.  Thanks for your help.